# element with negative z-index applied will not allow for hover state. how can i fix this?

Tags: hover, z-index

How do I get an element with a z-index of -1, that sits behind an element with a z-index of 2 to display a hover state? I currently applied a hover state to the element with a -1 z-index but it doesn't show through the top element.

Answer (score 0):

That's the idea of being `behind` it - you can't hover it. If you want to work around it you can create a 3rd transparent div that'll be placed on top of both divs and that will cover div1 exactly and add the `hover` property to it.